# Using pics/port/.style n args = {3} doesn't work correctly in \tikzset environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, tikzset

In TikZ i use the pics/ command inside the \tikzset enviroment to define the picture port, which is a element of a network switch. As you can see, the call of picture port in line 34 an 38 requires three arguments. The first two contains the values for the style attributes height and width. The third argument contains the port label, which is no value for a style attribute but rather the label of a node element. Unfortunately i don’t succeed to display the port labels correctly. The finished result doesn’t show the label 3 as i enter in line 34 an 38 but rather a mix of argument 2 and other indefinable characters.

I am assuming that you can only pass arguments, which contains values for style attributs.
If there is a better approach then mine to solve this kind of problem, please tell me.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    pics/port/.style n args = {3}{% style, size, label
        code = {
            \coordinate[] (main) at (0cm,0cm);
            \coordinate[] (labelposition) at (.5cm,1.2cm);
            \draw[#1] (main) rectangle (#2);
            \draw[fill=black] (.1cm,0cm) rectangle (.9cm,.5cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.2cm,.5cm) rectangle (.8cm,.7cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.4cm,.7cm) rectangle (.6cm,.8cm);
            \node (labelnode) at (labelposition) {#3};  
        }
    },
    rack switch/.style={
        fill=white, draw,
        minimum width=18cm,
        minimum height=4cm,
        path picture={
            %Gehäuse des Switch
            \coordinate (mainpoint) at (0cm,0cm);
            %
            \draw[top color=gray!5,bottom color=gray!40]
            (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
            %
            \coordinate (A-west) at ([xshift=0.8cm,yshift=.1cm]path picture bounding box.west);
            \coordinate (A-center) at ($(path picture bounding box.center)!0!(path picture bounding box.south)$);
            \coordinate (A-east) at (path picture bounding box.east);
            \foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6, 4.8, 6, 7.2, 8.4, 9.6, 10.8, 12, 13.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,0cm)$) pic{port={{thin, fill=gray!20},{1cm,1.5cm},3}};
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,2.2,3.4, 4.6, 5.8, 7, 8.2, 9.4, 10.6, 11.8, 13, 14.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,-.2cm)$) pic[rotate=180]{port={{thin, fill=gray!20},{1cm,1.5cm},3}};
            }           
        }
    }
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node(Switch1) at (0,0) [rack switch]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say `style n args={3}` then this literally expects three TeX arguments, which are *not* to be separated by commas. Just removing the commas gives

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{
    pics/port/.style n args = {3}{% style, size, label
        code = {
            \coordinate[] (main) at (0cm,0cm);
            \coordinate[] (labelposition) at (.5cm,1.2cm);
            \draw[#1] (main) rectangle (#2);
            \draw[fill=black] (.1cm,0cm) rectangle (.9cm,.5cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.2cm,.5cm) rectangle (.8cm,.7cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.4cm,.7cm) rectangle (.6cm,.8cm);
            \node (labelnode) at (labelposition) {#3};  
        }
    },
    rack switch/.style={
        fill=white, draw,
        minimum width=18cm,
        minimum height=4cm,
        path picture={
            %Gehäuse des Switch
            \coordinate (mainpoint) at (0cm,0cm);
            %
            \draw[top color=gray!5,bottom color=gray!40]
            (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
            %
            \coordinate (A-west) at ([xshift=0.8cm,yshift=.1cm]path picture bounding box.west);
            \coordinate (A-center) at ($(path picture bounding box.center)!0!(path picture bounding box.south)$);
            \coordinate (A-east) at (path picture bounding box.east);
            \foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6, 4.8, 6, 7.2, 8.4, 9.6, 10.8, 12, 13.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,0cm)$) pic{port={{thin, fill=gray!20}{1cm,1.5cm}3}};
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,2.2,3.4, 4.6, 5.8, 7, 8.2, 9.4, 10.6, 11.8, 13, 14.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,-.2cm)$) pic[rotate=180]{port={{thin, fill=gray!20}{1cm,1.5cm}3}};
            }           
        }
    }
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node(Switch1) at (0,0) [rack switch]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would not do things in this way. I would use pgf keys, with which you can use a comma-separated list. This allows you to set some default values, spares you from having to remember the order of the argument, and allows you to add more keys later on without losing backwards compatibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{
    pics/port/.style={% style, size, label
        code = {\tikzset{port/.cd,#1}
            \coordinate[] (main) at (0cm,0cm);
            \coordinate[] (labelposition) at (.5cm,1.2cm);
            \draw[port/rect] (main) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/port/tr});
            \draw[fill=black] (.1cm,0cm) rectangle (.9cm,.5cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.2cm,.5cm) rectangle (.8cm,.7cm);
            \draw[fill=black] (.4cm,.7cm) rectangle (.6cm,.8cm);
            \node (labelnode) at (labelposition) 
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/port/label}};  
        }
    },port/.cd,rect/.style={thin, fill=gray!20},tr/.initial={1cm,1cm},label/.initial={},
    /tikz/.cd,
    rack switch/.style={
        fill=white, draw,
        minimum width=18cm,
        minimum height=4cm,
        path picture={
            %Gehäuse des Switch
            \coordinate (mainpoint) at (0cm,0cm);
            %
            \draw[top color=gray!5,bottom color=gray!40]
            (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
            %
            \coordinate (A-west) at ([xshift=0.8cm,yshift=.1cm]path picture bounding box.west);
            \coordinate (A-center) at ($(path picture bounding box.center)!0!(path picture bounding box.south)$);
            \coordinate (A-east) at (path picture bounding box.east);
            \foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6, 4.8, 6, 7.2, 8.4, 9.6, 10.8, 12, 13.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,0cm)$) 
                pic{port={rect/.style={thin, fill=gray!20},tr={1cm,1.5cm},label=3}};
            }
            \foreach \x in {1,2.2,3.4, 4.6, 5.8, 7, 8.2, 9.4, 10.6, 11.8, 13, 14.2}{
                %innerhal von $...$ die x-Koordinate weitersetzen. 
                \draw ($(A-west)+(\x,-.2cm)$) 
                pic[rotate=180]{port={rect/.style={thin, fill=gray!20},
                    tr={1cm,1.5cm},label=3}};
            }           
        }
    }
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node(Switch1) at (0,0) [rack switch]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```